# Cannot connect dbt to postgres db running in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dbt

I got this project, https://github.com/lorint/AdventureWorks-for-Postgres, to create a Docker image run by Docker Compose.
This is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
FROM library/postgres

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install unzip ruby dos2unix

RUN mkdir /data
COPY install.sql /data/
COPY update_csvs.rb /data/
COPY adventure_works_2014_OLTP_script.zip /data/
RUN cd /data && \
   unzip adventure_works_2014_OLTP_script.zip && \
   rm adventure_works_2014_OLTP_script.zip && \
   ruby update_csvs.rb && \
   rm update_csvs.rb

COPY install.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
WORKDIR /data/
RUN dos2unix /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.sh
```

It creates a Postgres db Adventureworks with some data from scripts.
I can connect to this db from my local machine, by psql (or pgAdmin):

```
➜  psql -e -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d Adventureworks 
Password for user postgres: 
psql (16.1)
Type "help" for help.

Adventureworks=#
```

I am now trying to configure dbt to connect to this db.
I am using venv environment, with this requirements file:

```
dbt-core~=1.7.5
dbt-postgres~=1.7.5
```

I have this dbt_project.yml

```
# Name your project! Project names should contain only lowercase characters
# and underscores. A good package name should reflect your organization's
# name or the intended use of these models
name: 'dbt_tutorial'
version: '1.0.0'
config-version: 2

# This setting configures which "profile" dbt uses for this project.
profile: 'dbt_tutorial'

# These configurations specify where dbt should look for different types of files.
# The `model-paths` config, for example, states that models in this project can be
# found in the "models/" directory. You probably won't need to change these!
model-paths: ["models"]
analysis-paths: ["analyses"]
test-paths: ["tests"]
seed-paths: ["seeds"]
macro-paths: ["macros"]
snapshot-paths: ["snapshots"]

clean-targets:         # directories to be removed by `dbt clean`
  - "target"
  - "dbt_packages"


# Configuring models
# Full documentation: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configuring-models

# In this example config, we tell dbt to build all models in the example/
# directory as views. These settings can be overridden in the individual model
# files using the `{{ config(...) }}` macro.
models:
  dbt_tutorial:
    # Config indicated by + and applies to all files under models/example/
    example:
      +materialized: view
```

with this profile:

```
dbt_tutorial:
  outputs:
    dev:
      dbname: Adventureworks
      host: localhost
      port: 5432
      schema: warehouse
      threads: 4
      type: postgres
      user: postgres
      password: postgres
  target: dev
```

When I try dbt debug --coonnection, it doesn't work:

```
14:02:44  Running with dbt=1.7.5
14:02:44  dbt version: 1.7.5
14:02:44  python version: 3.11.7
14:02:44  python path: /Users/beatricem/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Sky/Documenti/Transformation/DemoDBT/dbt_tutorial/.venv/bin/python3.11
14:02:44  os info: macOS-13.6.1-x86_64-i386-64bit
14:02:46  Using profiles dir at /Users/beatricem/.dbt
14:02:46  Using profiles.yml file at /Users/beatricem/.dbt/profiles.yml
14:02:46  Using dbt_project.yml file at /Users/beatricem/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-Sky/Documenti/Transformation/DemoDBT/dbt_tutorial/dbt_project.yml
14:02:46  adapter type: postgres
14:02:46  adapter version: 1.7.5
14:02:46  Skipping steps before connection verification
14:02:46  Connection:
14:02:46    host: localhost
14:02:46    port: 5432
14:02:46    user: postgres
14:02:46    database: Adventureworks
14:02:46    schema: warehouse
14:02:46    connect_timeout: 10
14:02:46    role: None
14:02:46    search_path: None
14:02:46    keepalives_idle: 0
14:02:46    sslmode: None
14:02:46    sslcert: None
14:02:46    sslkey: None
14:02:46    sslrootcert: None
14:02:46    application_name: dbt
14:02:46    retries: 1
14:02:46  Registered adapter: postgres=1.7.5
14:06:47    Connection test: [ERROR]

14:06:47  1 check failed:
14:06:47  dbt was unable to connect to the specified database.
The database returned the following error:

  >Database Error
  connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Configuration file does not specify default realm
  connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: timeout expired
  connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information: Configuration file does not specify default realm
  connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: timeout expired
  

Check your database credentials and try again. For more information, visit:
https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/configure-your-profile
```

I have also tried to set 0.0.0.0 , 127.0.0.1 or my ip address in the profile (everything works as expected connecting by psql), but dbt doesn't work.

The error on GSS auth seems really senseless, this is Postgres conf file auth section:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust

host all all all scram-sha-256
```

How can I solve?

Comment: I also tried to use ```POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust``` in my docker-compose.yml env section. I can even see now: ```host all all all trust``` in auth section of conf file, but I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

It is actually an issue of `psycopg2` (Python library to connect to Postgres), with version >2.9.6. 
Setting `psycopg2-binary==2.9.6` in the requirements file for venv fix the issues. More details on https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/9303